# awk + fit syntax for SUN solaris & linux

Tags: solaris

need help about the following

when I run the following command on linux its run fine

```
 awk -v NAME=MACHINE '$1 == NAME'  /etc/hosts
```

but on SUN Solaris I get the following:

```
 awk -v NAME=MACHINE '$1 == NAME'  /etc/hosts  
 awk: syntax error near line 1 
 awk: bailing out near line 1
```

how to fit the following syntax in order to fit also SUN Solaris? or change in order to fit both on linux and SUN Solaris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` or `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` instead of `awk`

or

```
awk 'BEGIN {NAME=MACHINE} $1 == NAME'  /etc/hosts
```

or

```
awk -v NAME=MACHINE '$1 == NAME {print}'  /etc/hosts
```

or some combination of the above.